# Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I am creating a table from an existing view but getting error - **"ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object "**.

When I run the below command in sql developer it is creating the table with data but while executing the same on unix environment it gets failed i.e the table gets created with no data.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM myView;
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

I used below query to check if the object_name(table1) is in use but it returns nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE object_name = upper('table1') and OWNER = upper('your_schema')
```

Comment: well if you created the table once, did you create it as a different owner?   Did you drop the table before trying from unix?  run the select again w/o the OWNER constraint.  Also no need to do upper('table1') just object_name = 'TABLE1'  If the table gets created, then you would not get an ORA error.   I feel like you are not showing all the details.

Comment: I created the table with same owner. On unix, I drop the table and then creating it. Table gets created - but there is no data.  On executing the select again w/o the OWNER constraint, there is no data.

Comment: If `select * from user_objects where object_name = 'TABLE1'` returns nothing, you shouldn't get the error in normal circumstances. One thing to check is whether you have a glogin.sql file on the unix server setting your current_schema to something. `select sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual` to check. If it is set, you can set it back to you `alter session set current_schema=yourusername` and then retry the create table. You can also bypass the glogin.sql by setting the SQL_PATH environment variable to some random directory.

Comment: Also double check that you are actually connecting to the same database!

Answer (score 2):

The name space where conflicts is possible is in your local schema.

You can have a table called TABLE1 in your schema and 100 other times across 100 other schemas in the database.

```
 create table table1 (a integer);
 create table table1 (a varchar2(20));
 create table jefe.table1 (a integer);
```

Running this will:

1. create table1 in the local schema
2. ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
3. create a table of the same name in my JEFE schema

What you want to check is -

```
-- first create a table
create table table1 as
   select *
     from user_objects
    where object_type = 'TABLE';
```

Now before we create another one, let's see if it exists already

```
select *
  from User_tables
 where table_name = 'TABLE1';
```

Objects are case-sensitive in Oracle, creating a TABLE like we did above without quoting it, puts it into the dictionary as an uppercase TABLE1.

So when you go to look for it, you need to quote it, and search on the uppercase name.

There is no need to use the UPPER() function on your query predicate. This can cause bad execution plan, just search on the proper string.

If you search on table_name = 'table1' - you'll get Zero rows.

[image]

> FYI, as a best practice DO NOT create objects with case-sensitive
> names or with reserved words in Oracle. You will make your life and
> your developers' lives going forward very , very messy. Almost all
> Oracle database developers assume all object names are NOT
> case-sensitive.